# What didn't Gaetano take revenge on Josto?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fargo-tv

In the *Fargo* S04, We see that after Doctor Senator's murder by Calamita and Gaetano, Loy Cannon captures and chains Gaetano. When Josto finds out about him, He meets Loy and surprisingly suggests him to kill Gaetano, thinking this way he can get rid of him without facing consequences by New York Mafia.

But Loy tells Gateano about Josto's suggestion and  lets Gaetano go, because he thinks Gaetano will definitely takes revenge on Josto and that will cause a family fight, letting him win the war afterwards. As far as we, the watchers, know about Gaetano's personality, Loy's decisions totally makes sense. Gaetano, a short-tempered and ambitious character, does not respect Josto at all and seeks any chance to lead the family business in his own violant way. This is the best chance for him to kill Josto and take control of the mobs for a valid reason: Josto's betrayal.

But surprisingly Gaetano does not take revenge. He even tells Josto that he accepts him as the Boss and with Josto's brain and his muscles, they can win the fight against Loy Cannon. Why does he do that? Could he have any other plans for revenge?